# PostSharp NotifyPropertyChanged Model - PropertyChangedEventHandler

Tags: wpf, postsharp

I have litle problem with PostSharp Implementation of `INotifyPropertyChanged`. PostSharp added `PropertyChangedEventHandler` `PropertyChanged` after compile time, but I need react from C# too.

```
Model a = new Model();
a.PropertyChanged += a_PropertyChanged;
```

Model implementation;

```
[NotifyPropertyChanged]
internal class Model
{
    public string A { get; set; }

    public string B { get; set; }

    public string C { get { return string.Format("{0} - {1}", A, B); } }
}
```

I tried different ways to add handler,but unsuccessfully. Is there some way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instance of class decorated by `NotifyPropertyChanged` can be casted to `INotifyPropertyChanged` at runtime:

```
((INotifyPropertyChanged)a).PropertyChanged
```

There is a helper method `Post.Cast` to avoid "Suspicious cast" warning:

```
Post.Cast<Model, INotifyPropertyChanged>(a).PropertyChanged += OnPropertyChanged;
```

Comment: Thanks guys, I do not know how I could be so blind and miss it!